# reload my web page with my data after get value from a form in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have an html web page. I analyze a sample data and send related plot and table contents to my web page and show them. In the same page I have a text area to get parameter of my next task. after getting the parameter from user, I should do rest of analyze and show another plot and table in the same page. As a result I should have a page like this:

[image]

I have app.py (this is part of my code):

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    tsk1_image = get_from_function_1(data)
    tsk2_table_content = get_from_function_2(data)
    return render_template('index.html', tsk1_img=tsk1_image, tbl=tsk2_table_content)
```

and I have index.html (specifically the part of the form is here):

```
<form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" class="form" method="post" >
            <label for="value_k">K:</label>
            <input type="text" id="value_k" name="value_k" placeholder="Enter k..." onClick="writeOut()">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">submit!</button>
            </form>
```

Now I want to reload my page with all of data and parameter again and have the final result. I've wrote this part of code but it doesn't work.

```
   if request.method == "POST":
        k = request.form.get("value_k")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Actually I should `render_template('index.html', tsk1_img=tsk1_image, tbl=tsk2_table_content, tsk3_img=tsk3_image, tbl2=tsk4_table_content)` after I get the value, but I don't know what should I do...

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Is the page reloading successfully? Or is it reloading successfully but without the data you need? You may need `index` to do a check for form data if the request is a POST.

Comment: The page reloading successfully without the data I need. without table contents and images. I think I should do the rest of the tasks in if part: if request.method == "POST". and then render_template with all data again :-? I'm not sure that this is the correct way. Would you please make an example with code?

Comment: Okay, I put this into an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is reloading but not with the data you need, that is because `index()` is just recalculating the data the same way each time. `index()` should have a check for if the request is a post, and then if so, use that data in the functions you have. Here's the idea:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    my_var = default_value_here
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_var = request.form.get("value_k")
    tsk1_image = get_from_function_1(data, my_var)
    tsk2_table_content = get_from_function_2(data, my_var)
    return render_template('index.html', tsk1_img=tsk1_image, tbl=tsk2_table_content)
```

This way your form data will be used when you reload the data.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I should first render_template for first two task and after getting the value_k, I should render_template with all 4 task data. This is my problem: how to manage 2 different conditions and render my page based on them...

Comment: If you want the page to update with data after clicking a form, you should seriously consider doing this with an AJAX call that requests the data and then updates the page to how you want it to be laid out. Otherwise, `index()` needs to get the proper variables in order to calculate data and render the page, but it seems you do not want to pass it any variables that it will need to do that.